# Is it possible to implement the whole std::make_tuple functionality via deduction guides?

Tags: c++, c++17, stdtuple

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34180800/8414561) it is pointed out that deduction guides in C++17 will make `std::make_tuple` obsolete. However, as I understand, the difference between `std::make_tuple` and the standard deduction guides for `std::tuple::tuple` is that given a `std::reference_wrapper`, `std::make_tuple` will deduce a reference.

How can this deduction be implemented with deduction guides? Something like that, but extended to template `Args...` that `std::tuple::tuple` has:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
struct Element {
    Element(std::reference_wrapper<std::decay_t<T>> rw) : value_{rw.get()} {}
    Element(T t) : value_{std::move(t)} {}

    T value_;
};

template <typename T> Element(T) -> Element<T>;
template <typename T> Element(std::reference_wrapper<T>) -> Element<T&>;
template <typename T> Element(std::reference_wrapper<const T>) -> Element<const T&>;

struct A {    
    int i;
};

int main()
{
    A a{10};

    Element wa{std::ref(a)};
    static_assert(std::is_lvalue_reference_v<decltype(wa.value_)>);

    Element wb{A{15}};
    static_assert(std::is_object_v<decltype(wb.value_)>);
}
```

[Example](https://godbolt.org/g/DY1Ta7).

Comment: The reason for `std::make_tuple` is that it preceded deduction guides in C++17.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, sorry for being incomplete, I updated the question in the title.

Comment: It seems this question is [primarily opinion-based](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323334/5376789).

Comment: @xskxzr, rephrased the title with something more concrete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```cpp
template<class T> struct unwrap { using type = T; };
template<class T> struct unwrap<reference_wrapper<T>> { using type = T&; };

template<class... Ts>
tuple(Ts...) -> tuple<typename unwrap<Ts>::type...>;
```